# How to display image in android imageview from SD or internal storage

Tags: android, image

I tried below code but when,it launches Google Drive App and shows me error not valid format

```
String completePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/images/"+"rose.jpeg";
File file = new File(completePath);
Uri imageUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, imageUri);
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Use the proper two-parameter `File` constructor, rather than assuming that `getExternalStorageDirectory()` does not have a trailing `/`. Also note that [support for `file:` `Uri` values -- such as from `Uri.fromFile()` -- is being discontinued](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/14/psa-file-scheme-ban-n-developer-preview.html).

Comment: use this library for choosing images; https://github.com/coomar2841/image-chooser-library

Comment: The above code is working fine for  pdf format file, but on jpeg format it show error. i don't understand why Google Drive app is launching.